# Codeigniter where multiple values and 2 conditions

Tags: php, codeigniter

It's my first time with arrays, and I would delete some rows from MySQL in a multiple where values in 2 conditions.
This is the query that I expect, but stunk in this

```
DELETE FROM `tb_product` WHERE `product` = 32 AND `category` != '1,3,5'
```

I have tryout with array, but return this:

```
DELETE FROM `tb_product` WHERE `product` = `Array` AND `category` != `Array`
```

Model:

```
public function delete($data) {
    return $this->db->delete('td_product', $data);
}
```

Controller:

```
if($this->produtos_model->verificar_categorias($id)) {
    $data_del[] = array(
        'product'     => $id,
        'category'    => $this->input->post('categories'),
    );
    $this->produtos_model->delete($data_del);
}
```

View:

```
<select name="categorias[]">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Cotton</option>
  <option value="2">Polyester</option>
  <option value="3" selected="selected">Denim</option>
  <option value="4">Jeans</option>
  <option value="5" selected="selected">Soft</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your post has typos in it.

Comment: I am guessing that you want something similar to `return $this->db->where('product', $data[0]['product'])->where_not_in('category', $data[0]['category'])->delete('td_product');` but I don't understand why you are adding depth to the data structure passed from the controller to the model.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you, Work! about depth, I don't know a better way to do this, as I type, it's my first time with array, thought this is the correct way

Comment: `$data_del[] =` to `$data_del =`